# Swift - override tableview function - Method does not override any method from its superclass

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, uisearchcontroller, mklocalsearchrequest

I want to implement UISearchController, going step by step using this tutorial:

[Search for places using MKLocalSearchRequest and display results with UISearchController](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/)

And in this section...

[Search for locations using MKLocalSearchRequest](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/#4)

...I have an issue with step 3.Set up the Table View Data Source

```
extension LocationSearchTable {
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return matchingItems.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!
    let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
    cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
    return cell
  }
}
```

[image: Error:Method does not override any method from its superclass]

I'm trying to remove `override` from `cellForRowAtindexPath` tableView function, in this case i have no error in Xcode, but have an error after execution:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7ff8e03a3800; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H;
gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x604002046450>; layer = <CALayer: 0x604001626620>; 
contentOffset: {0, -56}; contentSize: {375, 132};adjustedContentInset: {56, 0, 0, 0}>) 
failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource(<CityWeather.LocationSearchTable: 0x7ff8de696e60>)'
```

Error message yells: `failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource(<CityWeather.LocationSearchTable: 0x7ff8de696e60>)`

Please tell me, what I'm doing wrong? And how can I handle this issue?? Thanks.

Comment: Please describe your Xcode or Swift version?

Comment: You can help yourself, it's very easy. Comment out the entire method, retype a few characters and use code completion. The tutorial you followed is most likely for Swift 2

Comment: less copy paste and more writing!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [tutorial](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/) is using old syntax for [UITableviewDatasource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) methods(maybe Swift 2.2):

You need these now :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

}
```

Always use XCode's code completion wherever possible.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me!

Answer (score 3):

As Puneet Sharma said you do not need to override methods. Because you are using `UITableViewDatasource` (and `UITableViewDelegate`) in an `UIViewController`.

You need to set the delegate of the `tableView` in your `ViewController`.